# How to recover the concrete type from Any

Tags: casting, rust, any

Code:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::any::Any;

fn any_to_u16(value: &dyn Any)
{
    let v = value as u16;
}

fn main() 
{
    let x = true;
    any_to_u16(&x);
}
```

Erorr :

```
error[E0606]: casting `&(dyn std::any::Any + 'static)` as `u16` is invalid
 --> src/lib.rs:6:13
  |
6 |     let v = value as u16;
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: cast through a raw pointer first
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1d5ecf601afa1d70d3e5f2ea46b3418b)
How to fix?

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code does not match the title, and what if `value` is a vector of strings, for example?

Comment: Auto-conversion between data types.

Comment: `Any` can be anything: you do understand that you cannot convert anything to an `u16` or a `bool`, right? The conversion must actually make sense

Comment: It sounds like you want a predicate function instead, which is the most reasonable way to map a value to either `true` or `false`.

Comment: I want to convert bool-> u16.
For example: If the value var_bool == true then var_u16 == 0x01.

Answer (score 1):

You must use [`Any::downcast_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_ref):

```
use std::any::Any;

fn any_to_u16(value: &dyn Any)
{
    if let Some(value) = value.downcast_ref::<bool>().map(|b| *b as u16) {
        // value is a `bool`
        assert_eq!(value, 1);
    }
}

fn main() 
{
    let x = true;
    any_to_u16(&x);
}
```

Comment: Given the comments I think the OP actually wants to use ˋTryInto`. In any case, this function in no way works for any type.